# Kind of group by in Excel without VBA

Tags: excel

I need another transformation help in Excel

```
     | A   | B      |
  ---| ----|--------|
   1 | ID  | Course |
   2 | 1   | A1     |
   3 | 1   | A2     |
   4 | 2   | A1     |
   5 | 3   | A2     |
```

I want to have a kind of group by, i.e.

```
     | A   | B       | C       |D        | ...
  ---| ----|---------|---------|---------|----
   1 | ID  | Course1 | Course2 | Course3 | ...
   2 | 1   | A1      | A2      |         | ...
   3 | 2   | A1      |         |         | ...
   4 | 3   | A2      |         |         | ...
```

Any ideas? Is it possible without VBA macro?

Comment: So what exactly do you want? Do you need a formula, VBA script or...?

Comment: What have you tried?? Are you looking for a reusable VBA concept? Is it going into a new worksheet?

Comment: @RobertJ. Sorry, I changed my question. Is this transformation possible without VBA. With VBA almost everything is possible and is not really a problem for me. Just didn't want to invent the wheel again

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow as it's not about programming described neither in the `excel` tag excerpt nor help-centre. Try asking it on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com)

Comment: @mehow i'm sorry ... you are right of course, I just thought it's a kind handling problems with excel and could be seen as programming. And I solved the problem with VBA

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the following link on removing duplicates from column would suit your needs (in your case you would do it horizontally).

http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/03/30/how-to-extract-a-unique-list-and-the-duplicates-in-excel-from-one-column/

Answer (score 0):

Per your reply to Robert, if you want to do it without VBA, try this... Select all cells in the first column. Copy and paste them into the first column of another worksheet. Use Excel's Remove Duplicates function on the pasted data. Then use INDEX functions in the columns to the right in order to pull the first, second, etc values matching that first column value.